# Spyder & IronPython (can the former use the latter??)

Tags: .net, ide, ironpython, spyder

Very simply put, I have been trying to use IronPython with the Spyder IDE.

Typing spyder and ironpython in Google provide very few results. I've tried to change the interpreter in spyder. There always seems to be a missing package.

I believe my question is explicit, but please let me know if more information is required.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The list of supported python distributions in [the documentation](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/master/README.md) as well as [this discussion](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/671) implies that there is no active support. Have you tried setting iron python as the interpreter?

Comment: Yes I have. I was a little surprised to find so little information on the subject.

Comment: did you try pythonnet? it works as bridge between cpython and ironpython!

Comment: spyder requires qt, optionally ipython, scipy, numpy, matplotlib - none of which work in ironpython